# Domain user cannot connect to Exchange

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I can login to the local PC and connect to Exchange server - on the same physical network if i log into the domain i cannot connect to the Exchange server.

DNS / DHCP all functioning as expected. User has AD account with Domain Admin rights.

Quite confusing!

Comment: Could you give us more specifics?

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume that this is Exchange 2003, and you're accessing Exchange using Outlook?  Just for some clarification, this is a workstation that is joined to the domain, and you're trying this with an AD user and with a local user?  When you're using the local user, and you say it is working, are you being prompted for domain credentials and entering the AD account (domain\user name)?  Is this the same account that you later log on to the workstation as when it does not connect?  When you are unable to connect, are you getting any kind of error message?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

HI Joe,

Not sure what else i can tell you - I i don't log into the domain i can access Exchange - if i do i cannot. IP address, gateway are the same in both cases. the workstation is always on the same physical network as the Exchange server. Exchange is part of SBS server 2003 R2 (at least i think it is R2 - not in front of the server right now.

If there is any information that i could provide that would be of benefit in resolving this please let me know.

Regards

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the domain user account is a member of the Domain Admins group. That is the problem. The Domain Admins group by default has Deny permissions on all of the mailbox databases. This is by design to prevent Domain Admins from automatically having access to all user mailboxes. You can either manually edit the permissions for the Domain Admins group or, better yet, use a different account or remove the user from Domain Admins.